# JFileChooser that manually picks the file

Tags: java, swing, load, jtextarea, jfilechooser

I was just wondering. Is there any way to use `JFileChooser` but open the file manually? So I could put the directory somewhere in code before and then just load it?

Here is part of my code:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        try {
            File plik = fc.getSelectedFile();
            Scanner skaner = new Scanner(plik);
            while (skaner.hasNext())
                dialog.append(skaner.nextLine() + "\n");
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So I want to:

- Open file from directory so i won't have to choose the "something.txt".
- Piece of code that let me open another file in the same `JTextArea` one by one, by clicking the `JButton`.

What I really need is a piece of code that lets me load txt file (from directory) by clicking a button few times in a row.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Note, that if all you want to do is open a file, and if you know where the file is located, then why even want to use JFileChooser at all? A JFileChooser is not used for *opening* a file, but rather for *selecting* a file to be open. If you've already selected it, there's no need to use JFilechooser.

Comment: again, Why do you want a filechooser? why not simple this `File f = new File(fileNames[i]);`?

Comment: and to use JTextArea.read() instead of Scanner or another Zoo for FileIO

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setSelectedFile` method of the `JFileChooser` to 'pre-select' the File, the user will only have to click `OK` if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
       JTextArea directory=new JTextArea();
       directory.setText(System.getProperty("user.home"));
       directory.setEditable(true);
       JFileChooser choose=new JFileChooser(directory.getText());
```